# Opening a modal above another one disables the scroll of the first modal when the second one is closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have two pop up divs, one for login:

```
<!-- sign in Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade login_popup" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    ....
</div>
```

One for signup:

```
<!-- sign up Modal -->
<div class="modal fade login_popup" id="sign_up" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

The problem is when I try to click the sign-up pop up from login, closing the sign up afterwards hangs the first opened pop up(login), it doesnt scroll or anything.

What I need is to have only one pop up opened at a time and no hang up.

I tried triggering click on the second pop modal and triggered first pop up close. It closes the first pop up but still the pop up hangs up.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle for this to demonstrate the behavior?